# how to replace duplicates in row 2d array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an 2d array with chars 6x6 and looks something like this and Im trying to create an method witch needs to replace duplicates in row with '@' character

```
 a b a a
 a a b c
 a a a b
 a a a a
```

and after replacing with method should look like this

```
a b @ @
a @ b c
a @ @ b
a @ @ @
```

I have tried this method but no results "I need to make this work without libraries"

```
 public  void RemoveDuplicates(char[,] array)
    {
        char symbol = '@';

        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                int temp = array[i, j];
                int next = ++temp;

                if(temp == next)
                {
                    next = symbol;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does "without libraries" mean you cannot use [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: NO can't use it and i don't even know what  HahSet<T> is

Comment: "but no results" because you never change any entries in the array. Actually you would need a third loop that walks through the rest of the row after you have saved the character into `temp`. This is a perfect exercise to be solved first using pen and paper. Imagine every iteration variable of a loop as a finger which points on dimensions/elements in your matrix

Comment: What is the range of chars? a-z? Or a-z  + A-Z? Or any unicode char? The answer to that could change the best implementation. Is there an efficiency requirement?

Comment: another trap in which you have stepped is the implicit conversion from char to int in here: `int temp = array[i, j];` you actually get the UTF-16 Code of that char and not the index! when you increment it afterwards you don't move the pointer to the char, but you change the character itself! you go forward in the UTF-16 Code.

Comment: In summary, it need to check if the cell's value is present in one of the previous cells of the same row. To do this, you can use a third loop to rebrowse the row.

Comment: can `a` reappeat in the second row? without being seen as a duplicate ?

Comment: This looks like another attempt to get this homework problem solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960124/how-to-2d-replace-row-column#comment127157436_71960124

Answer (score 3):

You can use Hashset (or list also) collection (docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections)  to store your duplicates as follows:

```
    var hash = new HashSet<char>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
             if(!hash.Add(array[i,j])) array[i,j] = '@';
        }
        hash.Clear();
    }
```

---

Or list as follows:

```
    var list = new List<char>();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if(!list.Contains(array[i,j])) list.Add(array[i,j]);
                    else array[i,j] = '@';
                }
                list.Clear();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the fastest solution but pretty simple to understand

Considering this input

```
var data = new char[,]
        {
            { 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a' },
            { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c' },
            { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b' },
            { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' },
        };
```

With this code it will take each row, one by one, then replace duplicated values

```
        //for each row
        for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            //for each cell
            for (int j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //for each cell compare all next cells
                for (int k = data.GetLength(1) - 1; k > j; k--)
                {
                    if (data[i, j] == data[i, k])
                    {
                        data[i, k] = '@';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Result:

```
a b @ @
a @ b c
a @ @ b
a @ @ @
```

PS: You can improve a bit the code by iterating "data.GetLength(1) -1" as the last cell cant have a duplicate.

And skip the loop if the value of the cell is '@', in the current code you will replace some '@' by another '@' :D

Comment: it would grately improve the quality of your answer, if you could describe what the actual problem was to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The goal should be to keep track of all previously seen characters. So you need some kind of 'set' data structure for this. The easy way would be to use an [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0). This has an add method that adds the value to the set, and return false if the value was already in the set.

```
var seenCharacters = new HashSet<char>();
for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    if(!seenCharacters.Add(array[i, j])){
         array[i, j] = symbol;
    }
}
```

HashSet is part of the framework, so would not normally be considered a "library".

If that is now allowed you could provide similar functionality with an plain array.

```
var seenCharacters = new bool[(int)char.MaxValue];
for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    var c = (int)array[i, j];
    if(seenCharacters[c]){
         array[i, j] = symbol;
    }
    seenCharacters[c] = true;
}
```

But I would probably not recommend such a solution since it uses much more memory compared to the hashSet.

Comment: " replace duplicates in row" sounds like `a` could possibly reappear in the second row without beeing a duplicate.

Comment: @JonasH this method replaces duplicates in entire array i mean to replace only in row

Comment: @emideveloper I wrote you a comment asking exactly for this point..... since it is a very crucial information, may be you can try to emphasize it a little more in your post. May be change the example

Comment: @MongZhu now example should look good !